# How to stop database project from building

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build, database-project

I am using VS2010 premium, and I have a database project in my solution. I am only using this to store SP & function scripts, so that I can keep them in TFS and execute them against our dev DB.

So, I have edited the solution configuration to not build the project, which is working as the build output shows:

```
------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: SocratesApplicationDB, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Rebuild All: 15 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

But, because I don't have any of the referenced tables etc, I still get a shed-load of SQL03118 and SQL04151 errors/warnings which makes it difficult to find any 'real' errors/warnings.

Does anybody know how to make VS totally ignore my database project and to not try to validate anything (apart from dropping it from my solution)?

Comment: BTW, I did manage to find a work-around of changing the properties on all the scripts to be 'Not In Build' which does stop the errors/warnings from appearing. But it seems to me that I shouldn't have to do this when I have set the configuration manager to not build the project.

Comment: That behaviour actually makes sense because the assumption would be that you're skipping building the project because there are warnings and errors, so they *should* be showing them to you. Otherwise, how would you get that project back into a state where it can be included again?

Comment: Good point! I hadn't thought of it like that (as I never leave a .net project in a broken state). I tested your theory by breaking an assembly and excluding from build. As you say, the build works, but the compilation error is still shown. So I have accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on the project file in Solution Explorer and click on "Unload Project" (It's near the bottom) then it will leave the project as referenced in the solution, but it will no longer try to build it or reference any errors/warnings/messages from the project.

Also, a lot of warnings tend to come from the files that you have open in visual studio tabs (it tried to intellisense compile them and such and such), so try right clicking on your current file tab and "close all but this". This isn't necessary after you've unloaded a project though, because it will close all of them anyway.

In order to get the project back in your solution, just right click it a "Reload Project" when you're ready.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it has merit, but I'm trying to find a 'permanent' fix. Setting the Build Action properties does this but I'd like to find a 'one-place' setting if possible.

Comment: Go to configuration manager and make sure it is not set to build, as well as changing the build property on the script file to None (instead of build) - works for me

Comment: @David This is what worked for me, thanks! You may want to replace this comment with a proper answer below? It could help others.